# POCO object not fetching values from local settings json file in Azure Function (.NET 8)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, .net-8.0

I am trying to fetch local settings values into a POCO object.

here is my program.cs

```
using Ioc.Infrastructure.Extensions; // Ensure this is the correct namespace for your extension method
using Ioc.Application.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;
using Ioc.Domain.Shared;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;



var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
        {
            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("IocAppOrigins", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Replace with your client app's URL
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
        })
        .ConfigureServices(s => {
            s.AddHttpClient();
            s.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
                options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            });
        })
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            
            var myFunctionSettings = new FunctionAppConfig();
            //var s = context.Configuration.GetSection("Values");
            context.Configuration.Bind("Values", myFunctionSettings);


            services.AddSingleton(myFunctionSettings);

            services.AddApplicationServices(myFunctionSettings);
            services.AddInfrastructureServices(myFunctionSettings);
        })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

And here is my local settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "KeyVaultUri": "https://yourkeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/",
    "SecretName": "YourSecretName",
    "SampleSecretKeyForTesting": "H1d7#f$812!F9)Jkq31p&*d9!@Ld3wE6",
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ioc-prd;User ID=delphdbadminprd;Password=*******;Trust Server Certificate=True"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ioc-prd;User ID=delphdbadminprd;Password=********;Trust Server Certificate=True"
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:4200"
  }
}
```

and here is my POCO class

```
public class FunctionAppConfig
{
    public string KeyVaultUri { get; set; }
    public string SecretName { get; set; }
    public string SampleSecretKeyForTesting { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    // Add other properties as needed
}
```

But no values are getting binding into my POCO object **myFunctionSettings**

So I am really confused what I did wrong? or how can i resolve the issue?

FYI I am creating the POCO object to inject that configuration in my infra and application layer services and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

> POCO object not fetching values from local settings json file in Azure Function (.NET 8)

To get values and send it into POCO object, you can use below code:

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "KeyVaultUri": "Rithwik Key Vault URI",
    "SecretName": "Rithwik is Secret"
  }
}
```

**`Program.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        config.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var rithtest = new RithwikTestPOCO();
        context.Configuration.GetSection("Values").Bind(rithtest);
        services.AddSingleton(rithtest);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

public class RithwikTestPOCO
{
    public string KeyVaultUri { get; set; }
    public string SecretName { get; set; }
}
```

**`Function1.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;
using FunctionApp110;
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly RithwikTestPOCO rithtestsettings;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, RithwikTestPOCO rithtest)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        rithtestsettings = rithtest;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        
        _logger.LogInformation($"KeyVaultUri: {rithtestsettings.KeyVaultUri}"); 
        _logger.LogInformation($"SecretName: {rithtestsettings.SecretName}");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.WriteString($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        return response;
    }
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]